# Alamofire in iOS 9 Not working

Tags: ios, json, ios9, alamofire

This was working fine until iOS 9. What changes I have to make it work again. 
My self.result is a JSON array

```
func loadData() {
    let url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?count=50&access_token=\(accessToken)"

    Alamofire.request(.GET,url).responseJSON{(request,response,json,error) in
        if(json != nil){

            var jsonObject = JSON(json!)
            if let data = jsonObject["data"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                self.result = data
                self.numberCells = self.result!.count
                UIView.transitionWithView(self.mycollectionView,
                    duration: 0.40,
                    options: .TransitionCrossDissolve,

                    animations:
                    { () -> Void in
                        self.mycollectionView.reloadData()
                    },
                    completion: nil);
                // self.mycollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You left out all of the important details. In what way doesn't it work? Be specific and update your question with relevant details about the issue.

Comment: are you aware that since ios 9, Apple applies ATS to all outside connections ?
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

Answer (score 0):

I used Alamofire 3.0 beta like below,hope help u

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, NetUtils.httpUrl, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON{ response in
//            print("request=\(response.request)")
//            print("response=\(response.response)")
//            print("result=\(response.result)") 
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                let jsonStr = response.result.value
                print(jsonStr)
                if let loginModel = Mapper<LoginModel>().map(jsonStr) {
                    if let _ = loginModel.status?.toBool(){
                        print("hello")
                    }
                    print(loginModel.object?.uname)
                }

            }
        }
```